# Make a div responsive like a svg (text scaling down)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsive

So I've been looking for days and can't find a way to do that.

I made a WordPress site, and my homepage is displaying the most recent posts I've made.

Thing is, the content of a post is written with some specific layout, and it is meant to stay that way. The layout cannot change! I need the text to stay in the exact same place, even if it becomes way smaller and less readable when looking at the site on a smartphone.

Of course, the site is responsive. Only thing I don't want to be responsive is the content of a post.

I've tried a lot of things, but I can't find a way to make it... [This page](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#article-header-id-1) shows exactly what I'm looking for, except that I don't want the post to be re-sizable by the user. I just need it to fit the parent div.

```css
.responsive-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.post-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.txt-top-right {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.txt-under-top-right {
  clear: both;
}

.txt-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.post-content img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-wrapper">
  <div class="post-content">
    <p class="txt-top-right"><em>Div right-top corner</em></p>

    <p class="txt-under-top-right">
      Div following the one on right-top corner
    </p>

    <div class="txt-center">
      <h2>h2 in the middle of the page</h2>
      <h1>h1 in the middle of the page</h1>
      <h3>h3 in the middle of the page</h3>
    </div>

    <img src="http://cs.pes.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/default.jpg" />

    <p>
      paragraph<br> on the left side<br> of the page<br> describing<br> a lot of things<br> on a lot of lines
    </p>

    <p>
      Adress<br> City<br> Country
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand HTML/CSS/JS, but I am struggling with JavaScript... I can insert some `<script>` tags in my html header with functions in it, but I have hard times understanding what these functions do.

I'd like the layout to stay the exact same way, doesn't matter which device the user is on. For instance, I want the .txt-top-right paragraph to take this amount of space. On a smartphone, the font size shouldn't re-size and fill up more than this amount of space of the container...

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ehPb.png) of what is happening right now when re-sizing the window. The layout changes completely !

Thank you for reading, hope it was clear enough :)

Comment: The only way to avoid scaling is to use fixed pixel sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paulie_D, I have tried that but the text is still adapting and staying the same size. The layout doesn't stay exactly the same

Comment: this one (https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#article-header-id-1) without resize will do the job?

Comment: Hello Saeed, yes I was looking responsive, depending on the screen size... But I don't need the resize square at all